# Capture/Tap home network traffic

Tags: networking

I want to capture my Budweiser Red Light wireless NIC traffic. For those who don't know, it's a hockey goal light that goes off when a selected team scores. I would like to sniff/monitor the traffic to find out the website/server that it connects to. It connects in order to get its scoring information. Which in turn, sets off the goal light.

Hardware info:

1. ISP Modem > Stock Firmware Router 
   OR
2. ISP Modem > DD-WRT Router > Stock Firmware Router

TL;DR Tap my network, find where wlan data requests info come from.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to capture your WiFi traffic.If you control the router you can turn off wireless security mode for a while and see all unencrypted traffic.